# Checking Event Log writing Permissions without writing an entry

Tags: c#, event-log

I need to check if a user has write permissions for the event log. My solution right now is to write a test message in the log and delete it afterwards (so that the log does not get messed up, as the check for permissions is called often (every 3-5 Mins.) by some 'Healthcheck'-service:

```
const string log = "MyApplicationLog";
const string source = "PermissionCheck";
EventLog evLog;

try
{
    if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);
    }
    evLog = new EventLog();
    evLog.Source = source;
    evLog.WriteEntry("PermissionCheck Test Message");
    return true;
}
finally
{
    //remove the check messages:
    if (EventLog.Exists(log))
    {
        EventLog.Delete(log);
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to check the permissions without actually writing a log entry?

Thank you in advance,

ElKunzo

Answer (score 1):

Yes, AFAIK, using CAS. Decorate the required member/s with the `EventLogPermission` attribute, from there you can control whether you must have access, only desired and so forth.

This may well entail a little further adventure in CAS itself, however, if you're unfamiliar.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogpermissionattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I completely misunderstood the task (I did not read the task comments): I just had to add EventLog write permissions for the identity/user which runs the service, without changing the code ;-).
Thank you anyway!
P.S.: I used the following ‘how to’: [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/217-Setting-permissions-write-event-log.aspx)

Comment: No problem; in such a case it may be wise to post your own answer then, so that people are aware of each approach and the data is logically accessible to the community. Glad you're back on top of it now though, good job.