# Validate Eventlog Write Permission

Tags: c#, event-log

How can I validate Event Log Writing Permissions without using an try catch? I've read the following question: [Checking Event Log writing Permissions without writing an entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066630/checking-event-log-writing-permissions-without-writing-an-entry), but the Answer suggests using the `EventLogPermissionAttribute`. As far as I know I can't use this to validate permission, it just throws an `Exception` when it doesn't have the requested permission.

My code now looks something like this:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    try {
        var trace = new TraceSource("MySource");
        trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1000, message);
    } catch() {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger<MyClass>();
        log.Info(message);
    }
}
```

But I would like something like this:

```
public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    if(EventLogPermission("MySource"))
    {
        var trace = new TraceSource("MySource");
        trace.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1000, message);
    } else {
        var log = LogManager.GetLogger<MyClass>();
        log.Info(message);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse at the end it doesn't make much difference but using a try catch for logic just feels dirty.

Comment: I looked for a non-try-catch option as well, but haven't found an alternative. So, try-catch it is, along with a disclaimer that this should not be seen as acceptable program-flow if possible.

Comment: Also, in some languages (e.g. python) in some cases exceptions are preferred way to handle some *exceptional* conditions. It's just a different approach: LBYL (look before you leap) vs EAFP (easier to ask forgiveness than permission).

Comment: Thanks @J0HN it's always nice to get a different point of view from a different perspective.

Comment: i wonder what try/catch block would introduce if you use it. May be there is no API given by the framework to see whether you have permission or not. Then , its up to you to start writing the functionality that you want . For this you have to make use of some other API's via that you can infer this information . So those API's contract is in such a way that they throw exception when something is wrong . This is a contract defined by them we cant help it. As you clearly wrote , wrap this logic in a new function same as like EventLogPermission()

Comment: and inside the method the logic will be to use existing API's and wrap them with a try/catch block and return false if an exception occured or return true when there is no exception . With this you have already clearly seperated the functionalities of a method (Single responsibility principle) . For eg: whether a file exists or not , we can use Framework api File.Exists(fileName) , but the framework implementation might be in such a way that they do some check , without doing any check we cant determine the result. Or did i misunderstood your question ?

Comment: Hey @srsyogesh I understand what you're saying and of course I can write my own method that wraps the try catch. It's no problem it was just out off curiosity if an API / Method exists to validate permission without trying it. Much like I don't expect File.Exists(fileName) to open the file to check if it exists. I expect it to validate if it can find the file on disk.

Comment: Oh , i know that was a bad example related to File . That is the one immediately strike my mind . Ok , i understood that you are looking whether the framework provides any API which wraps everything and just return true/false. I am not aware of any such . Hope you will find what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
      UIntPtr hKey,
      string subKey,
      int ulOptions,
      int samDesired,
      out UIntPtr hkResult);

    public static UIntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new UIntPtr(0x80000002u);
    public static int KEY_WRITE = 0x20006;

    /// <summary>
    /// This method checks write permissions to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog which is necessary to create event log source
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if permission to create Event log source is granted, false if not</returns>
    public bool HasCurrentUserEventLogWritePermissions()
    {
        UIntPtr x;
        long err = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog", 0, KEY_WRITE, out x);
        return err == 0;
    }
```

Comment: Ha this is a nice way to get rid of the try catch, but after all we are still checking if an error occurred while opening the key. +1 for getting the try catch away, but I was actually looking for a method that validates permission, before trying to open it.

Comment: I believe this would slow down the code - this check would take longer than try-catch or RegOpenEx ... I am glad you liked this joke...

Answer (score 0):

OK. I Give up and this just to tell you the failed attempts. I searched a little, reflected a little more and the answer is disappointing: you can't do this the way you like.

I tried to find a way for checking `EventLogPermission` (Security permissions in general) without getting exception: FAILED.

Tried opening the RegKey without getting an exception: FAILED.

There are in fact [unmanaged APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) out there that may be useful, but I think if your application lacks even `EventLogPermission` who would give it `SecurityUnmngdCodeAccess`?